# CardView only showing first row of GridLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview, android-cardview, cardview

For some reason, my CardView is only showing the first row of images in my grid view. (or my GridView is only showing the first row - I can't tell).

I am dynamically adding images into the gridView and using `gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. Perhaps this is why the height of the CardView is not adapting? When I add android:layout_height="500dp" to the CardView, then I see all my images.

Is there a way to make the CardView wrap the content so I can see all of my images (other than hardcoding the height)?

**Please note, I cannot hardcode the height as the number of rows of photos is dynamic.**

**Only showing one row of images, even when there are actually 2 rows of images**
[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/m_photos" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/m_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="none"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced This problem few days ago.For this case, Wrap_content not working perfectly.So Use layout height in fixed dp and use dimention for that. it works for my case.

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/m_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/gvHeight"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="none"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp" />
```

Comment: This works if there are multiple row of photos. However, the number of photos is dynamic and I do not want to show multiple rows when there is only one row of photos.